# Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on null

Tags: php, plugins, ilias

I'm installing a plugin on an Learning Management System called Ilias. It's installed correctly, but when I'm trying to update it to make it active it gives this fatal error:

*"Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ilias\Services\Component\classes\class.ilObjComponentSettingsGUI.php on line 520"*

Which refers of this piece of code:

```
function updatePlugin()
{
    include_once("./Services/Component/classes/class.ilPlugin.php");
    $pl = ilPlugin::getPluginObject($_GET["ctype"], $_GET["cname"],
        $_GET["slot_id"], $_GET["pname"]);

    $result = $pl->update();

    if ($result !== true)
    {
        ilUtil::sendFailure($pl->message, true);
    }
    else
    {
        ilUtil::sendSuccess($pl->message, true);
    }
```

The mentioned line is this one:

```
$result = $pl->update();
```

And this is the 'included' file code:

```
    <?php

    abstract class ilPluginConfigGUI

{
    protected $plugin_object = null;

    /**
     * Set plugin object
     *
     * @param   object  plugin object
     */
    final function setPluginObject($a_val)
    {
        $this->plugin_object = $a_val;
    }

    /**
     * Get plugin object
     *
     * @return ilPlugin  object
     */
    public final function getPluginObject()
    {
        return $this->plugin_object;
    }

    /**
     * Execute command
     *
     * @param
     * @return
     */
    function executeCommand()
    {
        global $ilCtrl, $ilTabs, $lng, $tpl;

        $ilCtrl->setParameterByClass("ilobjcomponentsettingsgui", "ctype", $_GET["ctype"]);
        $ilCtrl->setParameterByClass("ilobjcomponentsettingsgui", "cname", $_GET["cname"]);
        $ilCtrl->setParameterByClass("ilobjcomponentsettingsgui", "slot_id", $_GET["slot_id"]);
        $ilCtrl->setParameterByClass("ilobjcomponentsettingsgui", "plugin_id", $_GET["plugin_id"]);
        $ilCtrl->setParameterByClass("ilobjcomponentsettingsgui", "pname", $_GET["pname"]);

        $tpl->setTitle($lng->txt("cmps_plugin").": ".$_GET["pname"]);
        $tpl->setDescription("");

        $ilTabs->clearTargets();

        if($_GET["plugin_id"])
        {
            $ilTabs->setBackTarget(
                $lng->txt("cmps_plugin"),
                $ilCtrl->getLinkTargetByClass("ilobjcomponentsettingsgui", "showPlugin")
            );
        }
        else
        {
            $ilTabs->setBackTarget(
                $lng->txt("cmps_plugins"),
                $ilCtrl->getLinkTargetByClass("ilobjcomponentsettingsgui", "listPlugins")
            );
        }

        $this->performCommand($ilCtrl->getCmd("configure"));

    }

    abstract function performCommand($cmd);
}
?>
```

I don' t understand the error as I didn't change any of the code and all these files were included in the plugin. I hope someone can point out my mistake, thank you!

UPDATE

```
protected function beforeUpdate()
{
    return true;    // false would indicate that anything went wrong
    // update would not proceed
    // throw an exception in this case
    //throw new ilPluginException($lng->txt(""));
}

/**
 * After update processing
 */
protected function afterUpdate()
{
}

/**
 * Get plugin object.
 *
 * @param   string  $a_ctype    IL_COMP_MODULE | IL_COMP_SERVICE
 * @param   string  $a_cname    component name
 * @param   string  $a_sname    plugin slot name
 * @param   string  $a_pname    plugin name
 */
final static function getPluginObject($a_ctype, $a_cname, $a_slot_id, $a_pname)
{
    global $ilDB;

    include_once("./Services/Component/classes/class.ilPluginSlot.php");
    $slot_name = ilPluginSlot::lookupSlotName($a_ctype, $a_cname, $a_slot_id);

    $cached_component = ilCachedComponentData::getInstance();
    $rec = $cached_component->lookCompId($a_ctype, $a_cname);
    if (! $rec) {
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: It means that this `ilPlugin::getPluginObject` is returning `null`

Comment: On the line `$pl = ilPlugin::getPluginObject($_GET["ctype"], $_GET["cname"], $_GET["slot_id"], $_GET["pname"]);` the value returned from `ilPlugin::getPluginObject(...)` is null which is probably a result of the query string passed in the request. Can you provide more information on what is passed in the request?

Comment: @Bonner I can't find any of $_GET["ctype"], $_GET["cname"], $_GET["slot_id"], $_GET["pname"] in the ilPlugin.php file. Might this be the problem?

Comment: The `$_GET["ctype"]`, etc comes from the request, ie if I visit `http://www.google.co.uk/?q=test` then `$_GET['q']` would have the value of `test` so you either need to check these values have been passed in the request.

Comment: @Bonner I think I found the problem. I updated the question with part of the ilPlugin class. Could it be that the commented out section is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is indicated by the following item in your output (see comments):

```
$_GET["pname"] --> string(26) "SystemNotifications-master"
```

Probably by checking out from the GIT-Repo you created a folder named "SystemNotifications-master". This does not match the naming convention that the plugin folder must have in ILIAS, which would probably be in this case: "SystemNotifications". It must match parts of the php plugin class (which probably is something like il**SystemNotifications**Plugin).

In any case, do not change the core code of ILIAS. The problem is surely not there, but in your file system/database.

Comment: Thank you so much! indeed removing the '-master'  part was enough. I am now able to update and activate it.

Comment: Since this question does not belong to the previous, I think it would be best to try to formulate brand new question in stackoverflow.

Comment: Did so! The title is ' Developping an ILIAS plugin' .